# I am trying to retrieve a pdf from that is stored in the database however, it returns the path not the file itself

Tags: javascript, html, css, web2py

I feel like this is something minor that I'm missing but here's my problem. I'm uploading a pdf to the DB and then having another user retrieve it.

The form is set up in a table where the table contains the user's information such as age, GPA etc and at the end, a link to a pdf of their resume.

However, instead of the link, web2py returns me the path to where the pdf is stored in the filesystem.

Here's my table:

```
db.define_table('user_info',
                Field('first_name', default=get_first_name()),
                Field('last_name', default=get_last_name()),
                Field('phone', 'double'),
                Field('date_of_birth', dmy=['d', 'm', 'y']),
                Field('address'),
                Field('city'),
                Field('zip'),
                Field('gpa','double'),
                Field('income','double'),  
                Field('pdf','upload')
```

Here's the html:

```
<table>
      {{for user_i in user_info:}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{=user_i.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{=user_i.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{=user_i.gpa}}</td>
      <td>{{=user_i.income}}</td>
      <td>{{=user_i.family_members}}</td>
      <td>{{=URL('default', 'download', args=user_i.pdf)}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{pass}}
</table>
```

In my controller, I'm returning this:

```
def see_users():
    user_info = db().select(db.user_info.ALL)
    return dict(user_info=user_info)
```

My output that I'm getting from the table in the column for the pdf is this:

```
/ScholarshipWebsite/default/download/user_info.pdf.aafb1b2cb4664e28.4772616469616e6365204f6e6c696e6520416363656c6572
```

which is the name of the file stored in the system.

How do I make the above into a clickable link that can be downloaded instead of the path of the file in the system?

I'm using the default download function right now.

Comment: start storing a relative path in the db instead of the absolute one?

Comment: I think you're confused about how your framework or file uploads in general work, and how much of this a framework will do for you. I'm not familiar with web2py, but it's probable it handles file uploads by saving the file somewhere on the filesystem and giving you the path. It's your job to actually handle serving the file from that path, by either producing correct URLs that will let your webserver serve the file for you, or doing it in code. (The first is usually the better option.)

Comment: @LelioFaieta how would I go about doing that?, sorry i'm kinda new to the web applications side

Comment: @millimoose hmm maybe you're right but i was under the impression that web2py made that part very simple because i've seen many examples of images being served the same way. I think the hard part in my case is that its in a table and that it's a pdf. I've been stuck on this way too long though

Comment: I think all you need to do is pass the correct parameters to `URL` to make it point to where web2py stores the uploaded files, but I can't tell you where that is in your applications. Search your project directory for the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view code, you are simply displaying the URL rather than creating a link. Instead of:

```
<td>{{=URL('default', 'download', args=user_i.pdf)}}</td>
```

Try:

```
<td><a href="{{=URL('default', 'download', args=user_i.pdf)}}">PDF</a></td>
```

When using `SQLFORM` or `SQLFORM.grid`, web2py automatically generates links to uploaded files, but when you are manually building the view, you are responsible for explicitly creating the links and URLs (as you noted, the database stores only the filesystem path to the stored file).

Comment: Thank you, I feel stupid but this worked. I had tried this before but I think I was messing up the placement of the </a> and href... Thanks again!